# Snackbar: remove extra space below BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I am using BottomNavigationView and showing the network state in the snackbar.

When no `setTranslationY()` is defined, I get an extra space below the snackbar in both emulator and physical device.

**The issue I am facing is**: fixing a value for `setTranslationY()` can let the extra space for some devices and cut the bottom of the snackbar for others.

**So my question is**: How to properly set a value that is suitable for all devices?

Below is the custom snackbar:

```
public class CustomSnackbar extends BaseTransientBottomBar<CustomSnackbar> {


    /**
     * Constructor for the transient bottom bar.
     *
     * @param parent              The parent for this transient bottom bar.
     * @param content             The content view for this transient bottom bar.
     * @param contentViewCallback The content view callback for this transient bottom bar.
     */
    protected CustomSnackbar(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, @NonNull View content, @NonNull com.google.android.material.snackbar.ContentViewCallback contentViewCallback) {
        super(parent, content, contentViewCallback);
    }

    public CustomSnackbar setText(CharSequence message) {
        TextView text = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_text);
        text.setText(message);
        return this;
    }

    public CustomSnackbar setBackgroundColor(int color) {
        getView().setBackgroundColor(color);
        getView().setAlpha(1f);
        return this;
    }

    private static class CustomContentViewCallback implements com.google.android.material.snackbar.ContentViewCallback {

        private View view;

        public CustomContentViewCallback(View view) {
            this.view = view;
        }

        @Override
        public void animateContentIn(int delay, int duration) {

        }

        @Override
        public void animateContentOut(int delay, int duration) {

        }
    }

    public static CustomSnackbar make(ViewGroup parent, int duration) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_snackbar, parent, false);

        CustomContentViewCallback viewCallback = new CustomContentViewCallback(view);
        CustomSnackbar customSnackbar = new CustomSnackbar(parent, view, viewCallback);
        customSnackbar.getView().setPadding(0,0,0,0);

        CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params = (CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams) customSnackbar.getView().getLayoutParams();
        params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        customSnackbar.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
        customSnackbar.getView().setTranslationY(18f); // THE FIXED VALUE IS CAUSING THE ISSUE

        customSnackbar.setDuration(duration);
        return customSnackbar;
    }

}
```

And below is the activity layout:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mainnav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_bottomnav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/botton_item_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/botton_item_color"
        app:layout_dodgeInsetEdges="bottom"
        app:menu="@menu/main_navmenu">

    </com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I appreciate any help!

**P.S.**:

`setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener()` seems to be the way to go, but I get an error message because my minimum API level is 19.

Comment: It seems like the gap might be due to the `Activity`'s layout, and which specific `View` you're passing to the `Snackbar`. I would think that adjusting that instead would be a more robust solution than trying to translate the `View` arbitrarily in code.

Comment: @MikeM. I've added the `Activity`'s layout in the question and I am passing `CoordinatorLayout` to `CustomSnackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, CustomSnackbar.LENGTH_LONG);`. What do you suggest to solve this issue?

Comment: OK, I think I see what you mean, now. Let me have a look through the source code.

Comment: I think I got it, provided we are indeed talking about the same thing. That gap is coming from margins ultimately determined via the default style that an internal `View` uses inside the `BaseTransientBottomBar`. Those margins are cached in the `BaseTransientBottomBar` constructor to reapply later, so changing them programmatically doesn't have any effect. However, we can define our own `Snackbar` style to zero out those margins; e.g., https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mTwz6CKEVFBj0fA9rW0YtEnQCPNHr4QM/view?usp=sharing. You shouldn't need any of that `LayoutParams` or `setTranslationY()` code.

Comment: You are absolutely right! Defining the margins in styles solves the issue. All the `LayoutParams` was removed with no problem, but I had to keep `customSnackbar.getView().setPadding(0,0,0,0);`, because the snackbar showed shorter horizontally. Thank you. If you place your answer outside comment section, I will accept it as the correct one.

Comment: Yeah, just the `LayoutParams` and `setTranslationY()` stuff. I figured that's what you were doing with the paddings, so I didn't think you'd want to remove that. However, I just now realized that we can fix those paddings in that style, too, so you won't have to fiddle with that in your code, either. Just add `<item>`s for `android:paddingLeft` and `android:paddingRight`, setting them both to `0dp`, and you should be able to remove that `setPaddding()` call, as well. Anyhoo, I'll put together a proper answer later on, when I get a chance. Glad it worked for ya. Cheers!